# Joomla 3: display view with toolbar in modal

Tags: component, mvc, bootstrap, modal

I'm developing an MVC component for Joomla 3.x with currently 3 views:

```
VIEWS
|-PAGES (displays all pages in a list, ordinary joomla view) 
  |-view.html.php
  |-TMPL
    |-default.php
|-PAGE (forms for page editing)
  |-view.html.php
  |-TMPL
    |-edit.php
|-ITEM (forms for item editing)
  |-view.html.php
  |-TMPL
    |-params.php
```

In my page.edit view, I wanna call my item.params view via a bootstrap modal.
currently, I have this setup (working modal) (link in layout edit.php):

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_pages&view=item&layout=params&tmpl=component&id='.$elem->id); ?>" class="modal"><span class="icon icon-cog"></span></a>
```

with **behavior.modal** enabled.

**EDIT:** note `&tmpl=component` (administrator template disabled)

**How can I e.g. display save buttons and get them working? (with JToolbar if possible?)**

**Are there possibly beter ways to accomplish this?**

**EDIT:** I've tried @Dmitry-Rekun's answer and I'm glad to say it works! However I've run into [some issues with the implementation](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/how-to-get-save-and-cancel-buttons-in-a-joomla-bootstrap-modal-working)... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display them like in the ordinary list view. See for example [modal.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_content/views/articles/tmpl/modal.php) of the articles view. Just use `JToolbarHelper` to display buttons.

Or you can display buttons like in batch files:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.batch');">
```

See [batch](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_content/views/articles/tmpl/default_batch.php) of the articles view.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I get your first option (you can't display a toolbar in a modal without the rest of the (isis) template, can you?) but I think the second option will do it (I'll test it soon and you'll get the checkmark when it works :) ) Other options are still welcome :D

Comment: Displaying the buttons works! Thank you for that! Unfortunately there are still some issues :(

Comment: New issues = new questions ;)

Comment: They belong to the same problem, don't they? (I'm quite new here)

Comment: No exactly. You have them displayed, but issues may belong to another problem. It is better to create new questions. Editing the same question just creates the complexity and confuse to the answers.

Comment: ajay sir! :p Now let's hope [that question](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/how-to-get-save-and-cancel-buttons-in-a-joomla-bootstrap-modal-working) gets some delighting answers :) :p